# Check bluetooth state without asking permission

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Is there a way to check iOS bluetooth state without asking permission?

My app requires that the bluetooth be turned off, and when i create the CBCentralManager I get a request to turn the bluetooth on, so that i could immediately ask the user to turn the bluetooth off.

I do not actually need to use the bluetooth, just tell the user it needs to be turned off.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No. Accessing CBCentralManager requires permission, and it's the only way to ask for the state of the BLE system. iOS permissions are often not as granular as you'd like them to be.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683362/ios13-detect-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-without-prompting-bluetooth-usage-request (though there's no answer there, because there currently is no answer, the question elaborates a bit more).

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need the answer.
You can set the option CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey is false like this:
`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: false])`. It will call to `centralManagerDidUpdateState` but not request user to Turn On the Bluetooth